# Can spells with attack rolls crit?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, critical-hit

Do touch spells like shocking grasp or ranged spells like freezing ray get extra damage from rolling a natural 20 on their attack roll?

Comment: Missed that one in my search.

Comment: Don't feel bad - I couldn't find it either! Hopefully with this new pointer to it it'll be a bit easier to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes

The rule on criticals simply refers to “attack roll”.